# c# DataGridViewTextBoxColumn value set

Tags: c#, mysql, datagridview, combobox

I have a very complex situation, I hope I could depict.

So, I've got a datagridview which is looks like this:

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();    
dataGridViewFood.AutoGenerateColumns = false;

dt.Columns.Add("date", typeof(string));
dt.Columns.Add("food", typeof(int));

DataGridViewTextBoxColumn date = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
date.HeaderText = "date";
date.DataPropertyName = "date";

DataGridViewComboBoxColumn name = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();
var list11 = new List<String>() { "food1", "food2", "food3" }; // here later I'll use a mysql select query to fill the list
name.DataSource = list11;
name.HeaderText = "food";
name.DataPropertyName = "food";

dataGridViewFood.DataSource = dt;
dataGridViewFood.Columns.AddRange(date, name);

dataGridViewFood.AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.DisplayedCells;
```

And the problem is, the "food" col is an int type, because I storing the values in my database as an int (and I have another table, which is defining what number is mean what food).

And if I try to fill the datagridview like this:

```
[...]
reader = commandDatabase.ExecuteReader();
while (reader.Read())
{
    dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { reader.GetString(0), reader.GetInt32(1) });
}
```

The DataGridViewTextBoxColumn cant set the correct value.
So what I need, if the "reader.GetInt32(1)" is for ex 1, I want to set in the combobox to "food2", etc.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is `dt` in that last snippet?  If that is the same dt as above, you should fill the datatable using either a DataAdapter or a DBCommand object.  Not sure what this has to do with the dance with the combo column

Comment: Ahh, sorry, I'll edit. And yes, they are the same, but the adapter fill is not good for me, because the query returns with integers, and i want to set the combo box row to that integer, not fill the combobox list whit that.

Comment: That doesnt rule out a DataAdapter, it just means there is a step or 2 to set it up.  Are you talking about the totally routine practice of something like `[ {"apple", 1}, {"orange"}, 12]` where you show the text to the user but save the numeric identifier? Research databainding, dgv, combo and you will gets lots and lots and lots of hits here.

Comment: @Plutonix you are right! But im not the best at searching, can you show me something that would help me?

Comment: I gave you the exact search terms!!! `datagridview data binding combobox cell` brings up 61,000 hits! 13,900 on this site alone,

Comment: My bad, I meaned how to set the combobox? Because as I see the dt.Rows.Add(...) cant set it.

Comment: "research" is not the same as "google a code".  The latter works when you need a reminder of something like the order of arguments.  *Research* is reading articles on the topic to understand in some detail whatever new aspect you are programming - programming is more than syntax.  That said you will have 2 datasources.  1 for the DGV and another for the CBO column.  That CBOcolumn does the mapping using the DisplayMember and ValueMember.  It shows one but store the other in the DataSource for you (and you still ought not be adding any rows manually)

Comment: But I need to add rows "manualy", because I formating it, and I cant format with fill. I searched the last hour, and still cant solve my problem. I think this is imposible...

Comment: If the food cbo is a `{String, int}` pair and you are showing the name, what is to format?  If it is that awful date/string column, thats a different bad idea.  The DGV includes display format capabilities.

Comment: Finaly I did it somehow. Thanks for the help!